# Unable to enter text into text fields using WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I am trying to enter text into two text fields and I have tried nearly all element locators, Javascript tricks and the text just does not get entered into the fields. The test passes but I can see that no text has been entered.

The site I'm practicing on is https://www.chegg.com/auth?action=login&redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chegg.com%2F&reset_password=0

The two fields are email and password field.

This should work but doesn't, providing a snippet of the code:

```
WebElement emailField = driver.findElement(By.name("email"));

WebElement passwordField = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));

emailField.sendKeys("whatever");

passwordField.sendKeys("whatever");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: With By.name strategy, the first element with the name attribute value matching the location will be returned.I suggest you to use the xpath for more precise testing as well as perform some event in the test so that you would come to know success or failure just entering the texts doesnt matters to the tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in your provided [website](https://www.chegg.com/auth?action=login&redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chegg.com%2F&reset_password=0), two elements are present using `By.name()` locator where first is invisible and second is visible and you are interacting with first element which is invisible on the page. That's why you are in trouble, you should try some different locator to locating correct element, I would suggest you try using `By.cssSelector()` as below :-

```
WebElement emailField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".C-common-auth-signin-component input[name = 'email']"));
emailField.sendKeys("whatever");

WebElement passwordField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".C-common-auth-signin-component input[name = 'password']"));
passwordField.sendKeys("whatever");
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not able to find is because there are multiple matches for the locator. Try finding like this:

```
WebElement emailField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='eggshell-7']//input[@name='email']")).sendKeys("whatever");
```

If you are still not able to send, try sending a `clear()` before `sendkeys`

Comment: No, this `xpath` is not working because `div` id is dynamically changing...:)

Comment: If it's changing then we can try a partial match using contains and looks like the text box is the first match, so it would be: (//div[contains(@id,'eggshell-')]//input[@name='email'])[1]